# Change default permission dropdown from "Edit" to "Contribute"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We are using SP2013 on-premise. On a site collection there is a document library. There are several users with "Manage Permission" permission. Based on their need, they will change the permission on individual documents (permission inheritance is broken).

However, when they try to share the document to other users, the default permission level choice is always "Edit". Can we change the default choice to be "Contribute". (Screenshot for reference only, could get with EDIT access)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough rights in the library, I think you already have in this situation, you could invite/add user directly in classic interface of library for changing permissions.
Click **Share with** => Choose **Advanced** => Add someone in the library with contribute rights.

Comment: When I try to add them, by default access Level is EDIT, i can change it to contribute, but I want this to be default Contribute . Out come should be as shown in attached screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

When user click **Share** , in pop up you will find two options in dropdown 
1. Can Edit --> This will add user as **Contribute** level access
2. Can View --> This will add user as **Read** level access

[image: Screenshot for reference]

Comment: We are going through Advanced option, as permissions are being given at the Folder level Above suggestion works at document level.

Comment: Is your problem solved or need any other help ?

Comment: please see my comment

Comment: Can you elaboreate a little. Finding difficuly in understanding your comment.

Comment: If I go to one of the subfolder in document library . Click on "Shared with" => Advanced permissios=> Now break the inheritance => Click Grant permission => Here I see that by default EDIT permission level is chose, I have to manually change it to Contribute. ANy way to make it contibute by default?